# .net c# Anonymous Pipes - Misunderstood?

Tags: c#, .net, pipe

I have a parent windows form application and a child commandline.exe. Using a modified MSDN example  for anonymous pipes (h[ttp://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546102.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546102.aspx)) I am able to send a serialised object from the parent to the child. The child can deserialise the object and read the values.

Perhaps I misunderstand the mechanics of the anonymous pipe, however I am expecting the pipe to remain open until I close it, so that I am able to send another object across when I like, however after the object is send/received the pipe is no longer connected (determined by IsConnected property).

At the moment, once an object is sent from parent to child, the pipe is closed (not by "me"). I maintain a reference to the original pipeHandle locally but cannot seem to re-open the pipe. Should I be able to or should it not have closed in the first place? I don't see how I could open another new pipe, as I cannot pass the handle from the parent to the client (the initial pipehandle was passed by args in the first instance)

How do I send another object from the parent to the child?

I realise I can use Named-Pipes, but MSDN recommends anonymous pipes for IPC on the same local machine.

Many thanks

Arnie

Answer (score 7):

If you're doing like in the MSDN sample you are closing the StreamWriter (with the `using` statement), and [closing a StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.close.aspx) closes the underlying stream. The pipe remains open as long as the stream remains open, so if you don't want to close it, don't close the stream nor the `StreamWriter`.